# Submit pdf from form - HttpHandler Context.Request.Files[0] is empty

Tags: asp.net, pdf, ashx

I have seen a few questions where people seem to find this question out for themselves, so I will ask it myself.

I have a PDF that users need to fill out and sign, upon signing the user clicks submit and the pdf is posted to an ASHX page. The first thing I do on the page is this:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
if (context.Request.Files.Count <= 0)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Error");
    }
```

Every single time it is run the condition fails and "Error" is written.

EDIT:
Here is how the PDF is submitted:
 [image: PDF Submit]

***Solution***

Thanks to Joel's answer I found the answer. The PDF is sent to the page as a System.IO.Stream. Using:
    `Stream fs = context.Request.InputStream`
I was able to capture the PDF. Here is the final code I used to read the PDF into a Byte Array.
`public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

```
    using (Stream fs = context.Request.InputStream)
    {
        long len = fs.Length;

        try
        {

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)len);

                 //Rest of Code`
```

Comment: please post the code that submits it ?

Comment: It is a button on the PDF. On click it submits the PDF to the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF as submitted by Acrobat or Reader is an ASCII representation of the PDF. You just need to write the content of the submission to disk.

Comment: So is it possible to use this method? How would I capture the Base64 string in a handler?

Comment: I've only used PHP to do this but it was pretty simple, get the body of the message, decode the Base64, write it to a file with a .pdf extension.

Comment: I believe you have me going in the right direction now. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I went back in my notes and I was mistaken. It's not Base64, it's just a 7 bit ASCII representation of the PDF. You just need to write the entire submission to disk and that should do it. Sorry - it's been a while since I wrote that code.

Comment: I actually go it to work following the Base64 recommendation. I read the request into a stream and then used a BinaryReader to read the stream into bytes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.